# How to insert an array into text file(serialized content) dynamically in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, serialization

How to insert an array into text file(serialized content) dynamically in php..

eg: a:5:{i:0;s:5:"isn't";i:1;s:6:"aren't";i:2;s:3:"not";i:3;s:5:"isn't";i:4;s:2:"no";}

i want output like this..

data: "added"

a:6:{i:0;s:5:"isn't";i:1;s:6:"aren't";i:2;s:3:"not";i:3;s:5:"isn't";i:4;s:2:"no"; i:5;s:5:"added"}

Comment: This question makes sense, all I see is a serialized array that had the value `added` pushed into it then reserialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is simple.

In order to update already existing dataset, which is serialized, you must first require that file:

```
<?php $data = unserialize(file_get_contents('mydata.dat')); ?>
```

Then add the new field to the dataset:

```
<?php $data['new_field'] = "new value"; ?>
```

And then save it back to the file.

```
<?php file_put_contents("mydata.dat", serialize($data)); ?>
```

Comment: Thank u so much for your precious answer and its working fine....i wanna trouble u again..how to check $data['new_field'] = "new value"; is existing in the file or not..? since its a serialization getting confused.

Comment: you can use isset() first. like if(isset($data['key'])){...}
Or array_key_exists("key", $array)